# Join raster color with point layer

Tags: qgis, raster, point, layers, attribute-joins

I have a raster of the world considering different climatic zones. Then I have a layer with major cities worldwide. Now I want to join the information of colour into the point layer.
The option of direct joining is no option here due to the raster.

How can I identify the colour and related climate zone at each single point (city)

[image: points on top raster]

Comment: This https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/ may help you

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't about that plugin. Works really easy